# Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.0.RELEASE' not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am having a problem while creating a simple `spring boot` web application. I am building this app using Intellij Idea IDE. There is a issue arising related to the dependency. Intellij is saying - `Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.0.RELEASE' not found`(in `pom.xml`).

Detailed Error Information:

```
Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.0.RELEASE' not found.
Tag name: artifactId Description : The unique id for an artifact produced by the project group, e.g. maven-artifact. Version : 3.0.0+
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried to build on plain command line.

Comment: Did you try reimporting the project? Right click on project -> maven -> reimport?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am new to Spring Boot, so right now don't know how to build the project from command line, but will try in few days.

Comment: @Smile I tried reimporting the project, but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Building the project can be done with the command mvn clean verify for example in your terminal at the level of the root directory

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Easiest fix is to **Invalidate Caches and Restart**

[image: IntelliJ Idea Invalidate Caches and Restart]

Maven will then re-sync your POM file after the restart. No need to make changes anywhere else.

[image: Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE]

Comment: This works like a charm, but is there a better way? I get a "not found" error every single time I add a dependency. I'm coming from Eclipse where I had Maven > update from GUI which would get all dependencies.

Comment: Hi @lovrodoe I didn't understand your question, but I'm assuming you're asking if there's a better way to sync your pom file after adding a new dependency. You can do this easily by clicking the maven tab on the right and clicking the > Reload All Maven Projects icon (two circular arrows). You won't have to invalidate caches or restart.Also, by clicking on the spanner and selecting the Auto Reload Settings, you can set project to reload after Any Changes are made (auto update if build scripts or pom file changes detected)

Answer (score 4):

If invalidate `Caches / Restart...` doesn't work, check `Always update snapshots` from "File -> Settings -> Building, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven". For me worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem then I found a way to overcome that. I am not an expert on Spring Boot so I don't know what causes this but I can help you to fix. Go to https://start.spring.io/ then [Click on the add dependencies on the top right corner of the pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNj1I.png) after that select Spring Web under the dropdown menu, then generate the initializr again.

Answer (score 1):

For me, in intellij IDEA maven home path was incorrectly set to maven wrapper:
[image: wrong maven home path set in intellij idea]

Update it to correct maven home path

[image: correct maven home path]